# Python + Postgresql - Check if input values before add to database is equal with exist row value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I was googled around an hour but can't find a way to deal with it ...
I'm facing this issue. I have an input value (values before adding to my database)
. The problem is i can't find away to make an checkpoint or catch if my input value is equal with already exist row in my database (below image)

[My row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I5o6.png)

```py
def get_cases(update:Update,context:CallbackContext)->None:
  
    # My input value 
    location = "World"

    cases = get_Cases(location)
    print(cases)
    total_cases = cases[0] 
    new_cases = cases[1]
    total_death = cases[2]
    new_death = cases[3]
    total_recover = cases[4]
    if sql_cases_exist(location,total_cases,new_cases,total_death,new_death,total_recover):
       # I want to make an checkpoint/function here . Let said check if the input value it a equal with exist one. 

       # This sql update if the input value is not same with exisit one
        sql = """ UPDATE covid_stats
                SET location = %s ,total_cases = %s , new_cases = %s, total_death = %s, new_deaths = %s, total_recover = %s
                WHERE location = '{}'""".format(location)
        cursor.execute(sql, (location,total_cases,new_cases,total_death,new_death,total_recover))   
        conn.commit()
        count = cursor.rowcount
        print(count, "Record Updated successfully ")
    else:
        sql_addCases(location,total_cases,new_cases,total_death,new_death,total_recover)
        print("Not exist ! Add to database")
```

Comment: May be you should use the [merge](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html) ?

Comment: @BrownBear Hey ! Thanks for your idea about merge. But i finally managed to solve it :). By using an list and it work as i expected. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

for future search attempt. I was finally solved my cases by using List on python:

```
casesDB =[]
    sql = "SELECT * FROM covid_stats WHERE location = '{}' ;".format(location)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    # total_cases | news_cases| total_death|new_deaths/total_recover
    count = data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6] #count = tuple
    for item in count: 
        casesDB.append(item)
        # print(item[0])
         print(type[item]) => #list
```

then i compare 2 list of `cases` and `casesDB`